Downloading google calendar event attachment
I've been using google calendar to track events. In short, I'd like to grab these events and download the attachments associated with them. I'm doing this in Go, but I'm open to any working solutions..
What I'm attempting to do is:

Create an event on web google calendar with attachment (from google drive) using account A

read json credential file for account B (google service account)

  credentials.json [Where ServiceAccount and GoogleProject are my service account and google projects.]
  {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "GoogleProject",
  "private_key_id": "...",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "ServiceAccount@GoogleProject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "...",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/ServiceAccount%40GoogleProject.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}

and create a google.HTTPClient
    import (
        "context"
        "flag"
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
        "net/http/httputil"
        "os"
        "os/signal"
        "syscall"
        "time"
        ...... // Other imports
        gCalendar "google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3"
        gDrive "google.golang.org/api/drive/v3"
    )

    var googleCalendarID := "..."// The ID of SOMEONES google calendar

    var googleCredentialsJson []byte
    if googleCredentialsJson, err := os.ReadFile(
        "google_application_credentials.json",
    ); err != nil || googleCredentialsJson == nil || len(googleCredentialsJson) == 0 {
        log.Errorf("failed to read google_application_credentials.json:\n%v", err)
    } 

    var googleJWTConf *jwt.Config
    if googleJWTConf, err = google.JWTConfigFromJSON([]byte("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"),
        gCalendar.CalendarScope,
        gCalendar.CalendarEventsScope,
        gDrive.DriveScope,
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    ); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error loading google credentials\n%+v", err)
    }

    googleCtx := context.Background()
    googleHTTPClient := googleJWTConf.Client(googleCtx)


Retrieve calendar event using services reliant upon google.HTTPClient

    var googleCalendarService *gCalendar.Service
    if googleCalendarService, err = gCalendar.NewService(googleCtx, option.WithHTTPClient(googleHTTPClient)); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to start google calendar client\n%+v", err)
    }

    calEvents, err := googleCalendarService.Events.
        List(googleCalendarID).
        TimeMin(time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)).
        TimeMax(time.Now().Add(24 * 30 * time.Hour).Format(time.RFC3339)).
        Context(googleCtx).Do()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrapf(err, "failed to list events for calendar %v", googleCalendarID)
    }    


Download attachments using the file.url that comes back in the calendar event response

    calEvent := calEvents[0] // Just grab the first one until this works..
    if len(calEvent.Attachments) > 0 {
        rFileUrl = calEvent.Attachments[0].FileUrl // Just grab the first one until this works..

        var request *http.Request
        var err error
        if request, err = http.NewRequestWithContext(ctx, "GET", rFileUrl, nil); err != nil {
            return "", errors.Wrapf(err, "error creating request for file '%v'", rFileUrl)
        }

        var response *http.Response
        if response, err = googleHTTPClient.Get(request); err != nil {
            return "", errors.Wrapf(err, "error retrieving file '%v'", rFileUrl)
        }
        defer response.Body.Close()

        if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK || "DENY" == response.Header.Get("X-Frame-Options") {
            if tmpDump, err = httputil.DumpResponse(response, false); err != nil {
                return "", errors.Wrapf(err, "error processing response code %v", response.StatusCode)
            }

            log.Errorf("dump:\n%+v", string(tmpDump))
            return "", errors.Errorf("response code %v", response.StatusCode)
        }
    }

I've tried just about every url format I could find from my google searches..but every single attempt I am met with a redirect to google sign in. This happens even if the file is public (Interestingly, I can access it using the same url in a browser session that is not logged in to google). I can find tons of material on downloading files from your drive... but not a great deal on calendar attachments (either manually added, or added from drive). I'm not entirely clear on where files are stored when attached to a calendar event.. It seems like there's a bunch of redirects before the image is finally loaded?

I think your issue is that FileUrl has the format shown below which uses the browser-based Drive client and which requires browser-based auth:
https://drive.google.com/open?id={FileId}"

What you want is to use the Drive API files.get URL (with ?alt=media) which accepts the Authorization header provided by your HTTP client:
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{FileId}?alt=media

So, try:
const endpoint string = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3"
rFileID = calEvent.Attachments[0].FileId

rFileURL = fmt.Sprintf("%s/files/%s?alt=media", endpoint, rFileID)

Update
I'm unable to repro your issue making it difficult to help.
I added a calendar entry to my Workspace user calendar with an attachment (image of my dog, of course) from my Drive.
The following code works for me:
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log/slog"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    "google.golang.org/api/calendar/v3"
    "google.golang.org/api/drive/v3"
    "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

const (
    endpoint string = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3"
)

func main() {
    scopes := []string{
        calendar.CalendarScope,
        drive.DriveScope,
    }

    key := os.Getenv("KEY")
    b, err := os.ReadFile(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    config, err := google.JWTConfigFromJSON(b, scopes...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    subject := os.Getenv("EMAIL")
    config.Subject = subject

    ctx := context.Background()

    client := config.Client(ctx)

    cal, err := calendar.NewService(ctx, option.WithHTTPClient(client))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // There is a calendar entry with a (Drive) attachment
    // on {subject} calendar on 01-Nov-2024
    now := time.Date(2024, 11, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0, time.Local)

    events, err := cal.Events
        .List(subject)
        .TimeMin(now.Add(-12 * time.Hour).Format(time.RFC3339))
        .TimeMax(now.Add( 12 * time.Hour).Format(time.RFC3339))
        .Context(ctx)
        .Do()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, event := range events.Items {
        slog.Info("Event", "ID", event.Id)
        for _, attachment := range event.Attachments {
            slog.Info("Attachments",
                "FileID", attachment.FileId,
                "FileURL", attachment.FileUrl,
            )

            url := fmt.Sprintf("%s/files/%s?alt=media",
                endpoint,
                attachment.FileId,
            )
            slog.Info("URL", "url", url)

            resp, err := client.Get(url)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            defer resp.Body.Close()

            if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
                os.Exit(1)
            }

            out, err := os.Create("Freddie.jpg")
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            defer out.Close()

            _, err = io.Copy(out, resp.Body)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }
    }
}

Where:
KEY="..."  # Domain-wide Delegate JSON Key filename
USER="..." # Workspace user's email address

You can test using Google's APIs Explorer

Calendar events.get
Drive files.get


This doesn't seem to work either. I just get 404's back. :(

I'm unable to repro your issue. My code (added to my answer) works for me and downloads a Drive image of my dog attached to a Calendar entry.

You can't reproduce it because you added a config.subject, which I haven't seen referenced before.. but the issue was because of the config.subject being missing. I'm not sure where that came from, but setting the config.subject seems to have done the trick. Going to test a bit more, but I'm gonna mark this as solved I think.

You must impersonate the user account (with the domain-wide delegate) in order to access the user's account. Setting the Subject property is the way to do this.

How exactly is this supposed to work? It works on my calendar, but not others. So if I'm looking at some calendar (that is shared with me), I dont know what to put in the jwtconfig.subject. The calendar owners email? That gave me an error about not being able to retrieve tokens for that user "that way". My service accounts email? That just returns 404s... I guess I dont understand why I would need to impersonate anyone if the data has already been shared with the service account?

Respectfully, we're straying into "New question" territory. Domain-wide Delegation allows a user to impersonate any user but to access a specific user's content, you must specify that user (and acquire credentials to impersonate it).
